# Affirmations with question marks

Tags: grammar, question-mark

Today I was reviewing some code on GitHub, and end up with the following sentence/question:

```
So, are you using a context to update a record? That makes no sense.
```

I know that verbs and subjects are "swapped" when used in questions. What about affirmations with a question tone? Should it be written like this?

```
So, you are using a context to update a record? That makes no sense.
```

Comment: "Epiplexis is an interrogative figure of speech in which questions are asked in order to rebuke or reproach rather than to elicit answers" https://www.thoughtco.com/epiplexis-rhetoric-term-1690664 I think the distinction between those phrasings depends on how well the writer believes they've understood the intent of the code (first: uncertain; second: certain).

Comment: those 2 sentences are the same

Comment: What exactly is "So, you are using a context to update a record? That makes no sense."? Are you implying that it is "sentence" or whatever? It's not grammatical, by the way.

Comment: It's a sentence or affirmation. It's the same as if you remove the question marks, but with a question tone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the way you have it written is correct.

I do not know the word for this form, but as @sxpmaths said, it carries an implication of rebuke, or incredulity. You could make it more explicit with a [tag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_question), for example:

> So, you are using a context to update a record, are you?

Comment: Could you please clarify which one is correct? First one or second one?

Comment: They are both correct English, but the second way is more like a challenge than a real request for information.

Comment: They do not mean the same thing. Please also see my comment at the OP.